# Can I close statements in a transaction before committing it in Derby (JDBC)?

Tags: java

Basically I have (ignoring exception handling, etc.):

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
statement1.executeUpdate("...");
statement1.close();

Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement();
statement2.executeUpdate("...");
statement2.close();

connection.commit();
```

If I understand correctly it shouldn't have any impact because all it really does is free the resources for the GC. [Especially with Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/develop/develop63.html): You should explicitly close Statements, ResultSets, and Connections when you no longer need them. Connections to Derby are resources external to an application, and the garbage collector will not close them automatically.

However will it cause any issues with the transaction? I don't believe the transaction relies on the Statement. Can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: It seems, if you close a Statement, the _transaction_ is still open on the DB side (waiting for commit or rollback). It is only ended/closed when a commit or rollback command is issued to the connection. Am I right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Absolutely, you can close them, and you should.

Comment: I agree. But can it be BEFORE the transaction has terminated or does it have to be after the transaction has completed?

Answer (score 9):

Generally speaking, once a `Statement` is executed, the underlying datasource/database is responsible for ensuring successful execution. Any failures are expected to result in `SQLException`s being thrown in the `Statement.executeXXX` invocations. And any successful execution would result in the database tracking these updates in a temporary working area. Committing the transaction merely ensures that the updates caused by the statements are written to a durable store, from the temporary working area. This is often the case in most/all databases.

It is therefore safe to close a `Statement` object once you no longer need it, without encountering any side effects in the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is safe to close statements prior to committing transactions. You should have to read - [Closing Statement object prior to committing](http://www.coderanch.com/t/303444/JDBC/java/Closing-Statement-object-prior-committing) from coderanch and JDBC Transactions [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html).

Comment: I did, both in fact. The Java Ranch comments starts with "I believe" which is not confirmation, and no one furthered it, the discussion went on a tangent. The JDBC tutorial closes the Statements in the finally block, after the commit. And there is no mention of what happens if you close the Statement before. So please be careful in your comments, it's not obvious, nor is it stated in either of those references...

Answer (score 1):

Yup. Its a good practice and approach to close statement before committing the transactions.