# prepared statements sharing connection

Tags: java, sql, transactions, sql-update

There is an example that shows using transactions:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
...
con.commit();
...
finally
updateSales close
updateTotal close
```

If I wanted to move two prepared statements into separate methods sharing a connection/transaction, each called from a parent method, I do not see how to handle closing the prepared statements, since the parent method would open the connection and then commit it.

```
parentmethod:
con.setAutoCommit(false)
method1(con)
method2(con)
con.commit()
```

Do not need to engineer it as such. Just felt logical to separate out the updates.

Comment: why dont you close your stmts in your methods?

Comment: I thought since a transaction, it is not done until con.commit, which is in the parent. Parent would have to close them.

Comment: I performed the close on the updates before the commit. Not certain, but it appeared to work...How???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252368/can-i-close-statements-in-a-transaction-before-committing-it-in-derby-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the `PreparedStatement`'s scope set to the class level? The parent method could then have a finally block that closes all resources that the child methods may have opened.

This still isn't the best solution (generally you'd want the same method that opened a resource to close the resource).

The elegant way, in my opinion, is to keep the `PreparedStatement` calls at the parent level, alongside other resources.